# Wrong store value when calling it right after synchronous action call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

*I am using redux with reactjs.*
I am trying to access a store variable value right after the action that mutates it has been dispatched.

On a button click, I trigger an action like so :

```
submit = () => {
 this.props.updateChallengeStatus(this.props.password);
 alert(this.props.challengeValidated)
};
```

**challengeValidated** and **password** are bound to props thanks to mapStateToProps redux method like so :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    password: state.password.value,
    challengeValidated: state.challenge.challengeValidated
});
```

**updateChallengeStatus** is bound to props thanks to **mapDispatchToProps** redux method like so :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    updateChallengeStatus: passwordValue => dispatch(updateChallengeStatus(passwordValue))
});
```

I have checked, the passwordValue is correctly passed to the dispatched action.

My redux action is defined as so :

```
export function updateChallengeStatus(passwordValue){
    const credential = "c2VrdXJpdGF5";
    const challengeValidated = passwordValue === atob(credential);
    return {
        type: VALIDATE_CHALLENGE,
        payload: challengeValidated
    }
}
```

and my reducer :

```
function challengeReducer(state = {challengeValidated: false}, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case VALIDATE_CHALLENGE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                challengeValidated: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Here, i set the initial state of **challengeValidated** to false and then, when my action is dispatched, change my **challengeValidated**'s value to the action payload.

For some reason, my alert keeps displaying **false**. Altough i am actually sure that my state changes since I am using the react-devtools and my challengeValidated is actually set to true at the end of the process.
I thought this maybe because **dispatch** is an async call but after reading the docs it appears it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to view the content of a React component prop immediately after dispatching an action.  You can't do that - React hasn't yet had a chance to actually re-render and update, because you're still in the middle of executing the current click handler.  So, `this.props.whatever` will still be the same as it was when the function started executing.

Comment: I was so bothered by the understanding of redux that i totally forgot about the lifecycle of a component. Putting this alert in componentDidUpdate lifecycle method did the trick. Thank you